# AngularJs : ng-repeat with ng-form mark dirty by default

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an `ng-repeat` with dynamic data. Each item (user) gets a form through the `ng-form` tag.

```
<div ng-repeat="user in vm.userSet" ng-form="userForm_{{$index}}"> </div>
```

At one given point I add a user to the `vm.userSet` and I would like the form, which is created dynamically, to be dirty by default. How can I do this in AngularJS with this construction?

Comment: Can you describe your use case for this? There are only two possible states: dirty or pristine. The form is pristine by default. So you could check if the form was dirty or pristine ... but again since there are only 2 states it would always be dirty or pristine, so why check the state at all?  I'm sure I'm just not thinking of your use case...

Comment: I press on a button an a user is added into an array. The ng-repeat is bound to this array. Outside this control I have a button which is grayed out in case pristine. So the goal is that when the user is added to the array and the form is rendered the button is not grayed out (so it must be dirty). I am using the standard parent-child form mechanism. The button is linked to a parent form. If the child form in the ng-repeat is dirty the parent form is also dirty.

Comment: So it would be super cool to have an easy way to mark form as dirty by default when adding it. I tried doing something with ng-init but I was not successful at that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to make a directive per item being repeated. In this directive you can modify the form.

```html
<div ng-repeat="user in vm.userSet">
    <div ng-form="userForm" user-form>
        ...
    </div>  
   </div>
```

The directive looks like this (TypeScript):

```
export function userForm(): ng.IDirective {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function ($scope: IUserScope, elem: JQuery, attrs: any) {
                // make sure a new user is always marked as dirty
                if ($scope.dataItem.id == 0) {
                    $scope.userForm.$setDirty();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You an even put the form in the dataitem. This way you can easily get to the forms :) For example if you want to save all dirty valid items.